# magento 2 add custom fields to checkout form below shipping address form

Tags: module, onepage-checkout, magento-2.2.5

i have added custom fields (GST Refund ) to my checkout form but they are showing above "shipping new address form"
Screenshot below

[image]

I want to show it below address fields something like below

[image]

code of my "checkout_index_index.xml" is as below please help with what changes should i do

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="before-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="custom-checkout-form-container" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Bodak_CheckoutCustomForm/js/view/checkout/custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Bodak_CheckoutCustomForm/checkout/custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="custom-checkout-form-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-checkout-form-fields</item>
                                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="checkout_buyer_name" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_buyer_name</item>
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">GST name</item>
                                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="checkout_purchase_order_no" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_purchase_order_no</item>
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">GST no.</item>
                                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                                                </item>

                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can change sort order from your checkout xml like

```
<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
<item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_purchase_order_no</item>
<item name="label" xsi:type="string">GST no.</item>
<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
```

Or you can refer LayoutProcessor process plugin from this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227762/create-plugin-layoutprocessorprocess-vs-override-checkout-index-index-xml) and checkout customization steps tutorial from [this link](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/custom-checkout-component-magento-2.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the latest version of module https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form

It's currently rendered in a different way using shipping mixin and changes in default shipping template.