# Add additional info based on country selection condition in one page checkout country field

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, magento2.4, magento2.4.0

1. The condition should be like if the country is the UK then the text should not be shown. If the country is other than the UK then the text should be shown.

[image]
[image]

2. On the cart page, I achieved using the below shown two files where I simply add KO observable and made to show based on its condition.

[image]
[image]
[image]

3. I am using Amasty one-page checkout. How to do the same feature in the checkout page country field? I don't want to add a new field because in the Amasty feature the fields can be placed in any sort of order from the back end. So adding a new field will be affected when sort order changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. After few debugging. I achieved this via Layout processor plugin but it can also be done via `checkout_index_index.xml` layout. I choose layout processor plugin as it loads after XML which will make sure my code to work at last. Let me explain step by step in detailed. [Also refer [Create plugin LayoutProcessor::process vs Override checkout_index_index.xml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227762/create-plugin-layoutprocessorprocess-vs-override-checkout-index-index-xml) for more information]
2. As I am using layout processor plugin. I have a ability to give sort order. So here, I can set sort order as Amasty also used the layout processor plugin.
   [image]
3. Using layout processor I made a custom component and template file for country field.
   [image]
4. In template file, added p tag and did few more things to be shown based on KO observable value.
   [image]
5. Recreated the actual `select.js` as it is and added the logic to show the text based on condition.
   [image]